# DNS records not being discarded or updated, MS Server 2008 DNS W/ DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dhcp

I have a DC that controls DNS and DHCP.

DHCP is set to limit the lease for 5 hours and has dynamic updates according to: Always dynamically update DNS A and PTR records, Discard A and PTR records when lease is deleted.

DHCP is also set to update DNS and PTR records for DHCP clients that do not request updates.

BOOTP clients are also limited to 5 hour leases.

DNS is set to scavenge stale resources records.
5 Hours for the no-refresh interval
Refresh interval is set to 5 Hours as well.

Why do I still have DNS records with a timestamp from September..
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the scavenging settings set on the zone, or did you do the "all zones" setting on the server?  Is the box at the top of that dialog checked to actually enable the scavenging?

[image: zone setting]

Is the "Enable automatic scavenging" box checked in the "Advanced" tab of the DNS server's properties?

[image: server setting]

Comment: I got 4 minutes before I can accept your answer, I missed the enable automatic scavenging of stale records under the advanced tab. thank you!.