# Windows Server - Dynamic update of DNS entries for hosts with static IP

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, static-ip, a-record

I am using Windows Server SBS 2003 as a DNS server. I also have some other servers configured with a static IP (ESXi hosts, Linux hosts, Windows Server hosts, ...) and I want them to be added automatically into the DNS.

These hosts has their hostname configured, but they dont register to the DNS, so I cannot access them with their hostname, I must use their IP address.

Please note that these hosts has static IPs.

How can I make these hosts to automatically add an entry for themselves on the DNS server so I can access them using their hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to use DHCP, and configure **reservations** for those addresses from within your DHCP server.

Comment: (and make sure your DHCP server is set to create entries in DNS for its clients)

Comment: And if the host is deleted from the DHCP reservations and removed from my network, how does the DNS entry is removed?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/332492/dns-records-not-being-discarded-or-updated-ms-server-2008-dns-w-dhcp